# Using the constructor of a class in a different folder Python

Tags: python

I have a set of classes each with a constructor. These classes are in a folder (lets call this folder ABC). I have a separate python file (lets call this file PROJECT) that is in the parent folder of ABC. I would like to use the constructors of the classes in folder ABC in PROJECT.

I know how this would be done if they were all in the same folder but how would this be done if the classes are not in the same folder.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: You need to import the file (probably create `__init__.py` if not already created), create the object of the class. Search about these term and you'll get your answer

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I really hope the duplicates solve your question if not please [edit] your question and explain *why* these answers don't solve your problem. Just ping me and I'll have another look :)